# Page.Header.Controls.Add added style to body instead of head

Tags: c#, asp.net

Page.Header.Controls.Add method in **asp.net 4**
add styles and scripts in body tag, instead of add these in head tag

Can use another way to adding styles and scripts in head tag?

> Asp.Net 4

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, I am explaining two of them below

1. Using Literal Control in head
2. Using HtmlGenericControl class

I. Using Literal Control in head

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="tempApp.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:Literal ID="litHeader" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>
            Hello World
        </h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace tempApp
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            litHeader.Text = @"
                <style>h1 { color: red; }</style>
                <script>alert('Hello World')</script>
            ";            
        }
    }
}
```

In this I have made a literal control within "head" section and then passing my style and script content from code behind on page load

II. Using HtmlGenericControl class

WebForm2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="tempApp.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>
            Hello World
        </h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm2.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace tempApp
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var styleControl = new HtmlGenericControl();

            styleControl.TagName = "style";
            styleControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
            styleControl.InnerHtml = "h1 { color: red; }";

            Page.Header.Controls.Add(styleControl);

            var scriptControl = new HtmlGenericControl();

            scriptControl.TagName = "script";
            scriptControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            scriptControl.InnerHtml = "alert('Hello World')";

            Page.Header.Controls.Add(scriptControl);
        }
    }
}
```

In this I have used the HtmlGenericControl class which is present in using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace using this I can create HTML generic controls and later can add them on the page.

Still there are many ways to achieve this. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I used second way and I saw the resource files added to body instead of head tag.